# C/C++ Libraries for reading from Universal Disk Format devices or files

Tags: c++, c, user-defined-functions, iso9660

Are there any good free C/C++ libraries that enable reading from common devices with filesystems such as UDF, and ISO9660 and extracting files/metadata etc.?

So far all I've been able to find is [GNUs libcdio](http://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/) which is promising, and some ["Magic UDF"](http://www.binarymagics.com/site/magic_cddvd_burner_pro_vcl.html) which has so many hits I'm disgusted, pushes other results in Google, and comes with a pretty extreme looking price tag.

Cross-platform support is preferable (personal preference of course), and Windows compatibility is an unfortunate requirement. The less restrictive the license, the better, I have yet to investigate how compatible libcdio's GPLv3 license is.

Note this question is still open, I'll accept another answer if someone locates such a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive investigation, I ended up rolling my own solution to perform the operations on UDF that I required. I'm unable to open the source, in all it was about 800 lines of C++. However here are several links which got me through:

- [The reference standard on which UDF is built](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-167.pdf)
- [Universal Disk Format specification 2.60](http://www.osta.org/specs/pdf/udf260.pdf)
- [Brief introduction to UDF](http://homepage.mac.com/wenguangwang/myhome/udf.html)
- [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format)
- [UDF Verifier tool](https://www.ip.philips.com/partners/) (you must sign up for access to this)

A few words of warning: Previous experience implementing ISO9660/ECMA-119 helped me significantly. Knowledge of how block devices operate and interface with the operating system is helpful. Information surrounding the physical layout and separation of sessions is somewhat mythical and difficult to grok.

Comment: Is there a possibility of releasing your reader as a library?

Comment: @Dilawar: Sorry no. It was for a previous employer, and I've long since moved on.

Answer (score -1):

[7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) supports extracting files from UDF and ISO disk images, and is mostly LGPL licensed. Specifically, the UDF implementation code appears to be in `CPP/7zip/Archive/Udf/UdfIn.cpp`.

Comment: The 7z program appears to tap into COM, but there are is no actual UDF implementation code in the library.

Comment: @Anacrolix: The COM component it uses is part of the 7-Zip source tree.

Answer (score -2):

See: http://www.thefreecountry.com/sourcecode/cpp.shtml

Comment: I cannot find anything related there, at least not by searching for text "ISO", "UDF" or "9660".

Comment: Free, but nothing related to UDF, ISO, or any other image formats.

Answer (score -2):

There are a lot of open source library for this but reliability is question.

On Windows You can use Image Mastering API. It comes with Window SDK , Work on both XP & Vista

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364806%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: It appears IMAPI is for burning and creating images only. It doesn't open existing images or devices.